Enhance model performance in text classification task
I tried to build a model for multi-label text classification task in chinese, but the performance of the model is not good enough (about 60% accuracy), and I come for help about how to enhance it.
I build a model based on a github project:
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from transformers import BertModel


class BertMultiLabelCls(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, class_num, dropout=0.1):
        super(BertMultiLabelCls, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, class_num)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-chinese")

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids):
        outputs = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids)
        cls = self.drop(outputs[1])
        out = F.sigmoid(self.fc(cls))
        return out

My dataset is 2000 query-tag pair, having 13 tags and query about the questions asked by the audience in the live commerce. I splited the dataset by 3:1:1 corresponding to train/test/val. My tags are NOT balanced and no up sample/down sample strategy is used.
Loss and accuracy during the training process, where the horizontal axis stands for the epoch:

The vaildation accuracy stopped increasing near 60%, and same result for my test dataset.
I've tried various methods including adding more fully connection layer/adding residual connection, but the result remains the same.
Here are my training params if it helps:
lr = 2e-5
batch_size = 128
max_len = 64
hidden_size = 768
epochs = 30
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
criterion = nn.BCELoss() # loss function

Any suggestions about how I improve my model besides the datasets? because that what I am doing paralleling and I know how to improve it. But I'm really newbie about the network itself.

Hi, Bert is quite an old model. Switch to LLama, Mmistral or T5 or smth similar

Given your imbalanced dataset, Focal Loss could be a valuable alternative to BCELoss. It focuses on hard-to-classify examples, reducing the influence of easy negatives that dominate the loss in imbalanced scenarios.
Convolutional neural networks (CNNs) can capture local patterns and n-gram features, complementing the global context captured by BERT. Consider adding a CNN layer before or after the BERT encoder.
We can also implement callback and Monitor validation accuracy and stop training early if it doesn't improve for a certain number of epochs. This prevents overfitting to the training data.
